# What Book-Library  Organizing Programs are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, ebooks, books, organizer

I would like to ask if there is any good program for ubuntu 12.04 to organize a library of books.I want to mention that I also have books written in my native language (Greek) and I have books written in other languages like English,French, etc too .So basically I need an application which can fetch information from databases for Greek books.

For example - Adding a Greek (ISBN) book database source and when I type the ISBN of the book in the program ,it should find the book from that databases.

Is this possible? I  already tried **Tellico** and **GCstar** but they were unable to find books with Greek ISBN .I tried to add a Greek book source but it wasn't successful.

Comment: Have you tried **Calibre** , Install it from Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: Can you add real books or only e-books?If it can,does it have the ability to add where the book is placed in the library?And how do you add sources where it can fetch info for Greek books?

Comment: Only ebooks can be added, also supports fetching info from custom sources. For further info view [this](http://calibre-ebook.com/demo).

Comment: In which point exactly does it say that you can add custom sources?

Comment: Adding sources here means getting rss or news feeds from books site , see [faq](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#content-from-the-web). But if your source is  a network library, or book sites ,  both can be done in calibre.

Comment: "But if your source is a network library, or book sites , both can be done in calibre."<-------This is what I am asking for.How am I going to do that.

Comment: Just enlarge the right border on Calibre window to show all the option, there you will find preferences , [connect/share](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/gui.html#id36) option. also there are lot of plugins to install as per usage  and found a plugin for [greek metadata](http://webtropic.cc/2012/01/19/a-calibre-plugin-for-greek-book-metadata/).

Comment: Okay I found it,but I didn't work so far with any greek book that I have tried.Anyway,thanks a lot for your answers folks.

Comment: If one or more of these comments really did answer the question, they should now be *posted as answers* so people will see this question is answered and so el10780 can accept one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully added this Greek z39.50 source to Tellico, and executed some searches. I don't know whether the coverage is enough for the books you have, but you might want to give it a shot.

http://irspy.indexdata.com/full.html?id=Z39.50%3A193.108.161.35%3A210%2FADVANCE

```
ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ ΑΝΟΙΚΤΟ ΠΑΝΕΠΙΣΤΗΜΙΟ
Host: 193.108.161.35
Port: 210
DB: ADVANCE
```

Comment: Thanks.I can confirm it works for the e-books that I own.