# Are their any book cataloguing apps for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, books

I'm trying to transition from most webapps to desktop apps (partly due to pernicious overseas three-letter agencies), but I can't find any replacement for the book-managment site Goodreads.

I don't own any ebooks (my collection is paper-only), so from what I gather Calibri won't be much use to me; I want an app purely for cataloguing my book collection, though additional features are welcome.

#### Desired Features

The features that a suitable app might have (not all are strictly required):

- Ability to add and catagorise books.
- Access to that data, either directly or by exporting to json | md | xml.
- Metadata download from an online metadata API (amazon, goodreads).
- Book recommendations based on my collection.
- Gnome integration.

Do any suitable apps available for Linux? Any app even remotely converging on these features would be helpful.

I found a similar question, but it was more specifically about Greek language integration.

[What Book-Library  Organizing Programs are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154922/what-book-library-organizing-programs-are-available)

If my question needs refinement or additional information please leave a comment below.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tellico** is the best!

> Tellico capabilities include:
>
> - creation of user-defined custom collections with unlimited fields,
> - automatically formatted names,
> - sorting and filtering by any field or property,
> - ISBN validation,
> - full customization for printing or display through XSLT files,
> - import and export of CSV, RIS, BibTeX and BibTeXML files,
> - import data from Amazon, IMDb, CDDB or any US-MARC compliant z39.50 server,
> - tellico files are stored in XML format, avoiding the need for a database server, and allowing other software applications to use the
>     data.

[image: Download Tellico]